# Change plain line to arrow line in infovis

Tags: infovis, thejit

How to change plain line to arrow line in infovis?

Currently there are some lines between blocks, I found some css files, but I cannot find which content describing the line behaviour such that I can change the plain line to arrow line.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your exact graph generation code?

Answer (score 3):

Generally spoken: You can't (and shouldn't) change it via CSS. Define such properties during the setup.

Here's a brief explanation:

- The Code that generates and Edge (which is a *line* in network visualizations) is generated by the `Edge` method/function which sits inside [`Options.Edge.js`](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Options/Options-Edge-js.html).
- The function `Edge` is a property/module of the `$jit` object and works like this:

  ```
  var viz = new $jit.Viz({  
    Edge: {  
        overridable:  true,  
        type:         'line',  
        color:        '#fff',  
        CanvasStyles: {  
            : '#ccc',  
            shadowBlur: 10  
        }  
      } 
  } );
  ```
- It's important that you define `overridable` as `true` as you else can't override anything. The parameter that you're searching for is `type`. The allowed values are `line`, `hyperline`, `arrow` and I'm pretty sure that `bezier` will work as well - not sure if this is true for every type of graph. You can as well define custom graph Edge types - an example is missing in the documentation.
- To change the Line/Edge style, there's another function that triggers before rendering. You just have to define it during the graph registration `$jit.Viz( { /* add here */ } );` - code from the example/Spacetree [here](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.code.html):

  ```
  // This method is called right before plotting  
  // an edge. It's useful for changing an individual edge  
  // style properties before plotting it.  
  // Edge data proprties prefixed with a dollar sign will  
  // override the Edge global style properties.  
  onBeforePlotLine: function(adj){  
      if (adj.nodeFrom.selected && adj.nodeTo.selected) {  
          adj.data.$color = "#eed";  
          adj.data.$lineWidth = 3;  
      }  
      else {  
          delete adj.data.$color;  
          delete adj.data.$lineWidth;  
      }
  ```

  }
- The final step would now be to inspect what `add.data` can deliver and then either add the style you want or define a new one using a closure.

There might be another way to go on this: Example for a `ForceDirected` graph. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Graph/Graph-Plot-js.html#Graph.Plot).

```
$jit.ForceDirected.Plot.plotLine( adj, canvas, animating );
```

Maybe you could even use something like this:

```
var edge = viz.getEdge('Edge_ID');
edge.setData( property, value, type );
```

*Disclaimer: I got no working copy of theJit/InfoViz library around, so I can't help more than that unless you add a JSFiddle example with your code.*

### Edit

As I just read that you only want to change to the default `arrow` type, just enter this type during the configuration of the graph.